# How to get a token for downstream service in AAD

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have an MVC application in which I use [`OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect.openidconnectauthenticationmiddleware(v=vs.113).aspx) to authenticate the user against AAD. This MVC application uses a few backend services that require the user's authentication context.

If I register these services separately in AAD, I can get a token for them using 
`AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync`. But registering these services separately with AAD seems wrong as they would require the user to consent to them separately (they are really part of the application).

So I'd like to use the JWT token I got from AAD when the user authenticated and use that as the bearer token for calling the downstream services. I realize that these services need to have the same audience as the MVC application.

But how do I get that JWT token. The ClaimPrincipal's first identity does not have a bootstrap context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that having your services admit tokens with the same audience opens you up to token forwarding attacks. I would not recommend that. Also, the consent should happen in a single page and with a single click - hence in terms of user impact there isn't really much difference.
That said. If you are really set in it, you can enforce the presence of the token in the bootstrapcontext by switching to true the flag `SaveSignInToken`. See

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters{SaveSigninToken=true},
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
```

Comment: Thanks Vittorio, I've been struggling with that. We have like a dozen backend services, but those are irrelevant to the user or AAD admin (implementation detail). The user should only consent to the application, not all the services it uses in the backend. What would be the recommended approach?

Comment: As long as your app lists those services as required resources in its declaration, there should be a single prompt. It is true that seeing a long list of strings alongside the app might be confusing for some users, but it should be a one time thing. Another alternative is to use admin consent - in that case only the administrator sees the prompt and every user is automatically consented in afterwards

Comment: Ah, so I can list those services in the manifest and have a single consent prompt! Do you have a pointer to more info on this?

Comment: see the admin consent branch of the sign up controller in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean the admin consent. Where can I find more info on listing services as required resources? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the consent screen for the MVC app and its services working. Could you take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803806/how-to-consent-an-app-and-its-dependent-services-in-aad

Comment: I believe the consent would only be required in a multi-tenant app scenario.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#delegated-user-identity-with-openid-connect "This consent process only applies to multi-tenant applications..."
Would this assumption be correct?

Comment: technically, that's not true. Every app determines whether a request can be granted according to recorded consent. Say that A and B are both non-admin users of tenant T. If A creates an app in T, he/she might grant consent as part of the process; but when B tries to access the same app, he/she will be prompted for consent. The exception to this is if A is an admin, in which case the app might get an admin-consent at creation time.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** The below is one way to achieve this, but it has some security implications. There is also a flag you can set for using the bootstrap context. Please see vibronet's answer for more.

In the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`, if you configure a handler for the `SecurityTokenValidated` or `AuthorizationCodeRecieved` notifications, you can access the id_token in the notification's properties. You can then use that id_token as the bearer token in your service calls. There are several different ways you might make that id_token available in your controllers.

One caveat: the id_token will have the clientId of your web app as the aud claim, not the app id uri. So in your services, you should use the clientId guid as your audience.

Comment: Thanks, found the token. Shouldn't that token be available via the BootstrapContext? What would be the options to access that token from the controller?

Comment: Also in the notifications, you could add the token to the claims in the ClaimsIdentity. I believe it is in notification.AuthenticationTicket. Then you could read them in your controller via ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims. That's just one way though. You might also use the http session, cookies, or some form of backend storage.

Comment: Those are kind of one time deals. If you want the token always there, see the other answer. Also, please think twice before enabling the same audience on multiple endpoints... token forwarding is real :)