# How to consent an app and its dependent services in AAD

Tags: azure, oauth, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory, adal

I created a multi-tenant MVC application that has a dependency on two services in the same directory. The RequiredResourceAccess section of the manifest looks like this:

```
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "fc7ecdae-ec69-40a8-a88f-a859591fab07",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "058901ac-c903-4772-8ccb-d746b94ac86b",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": "66d17ca1-0084-4865-baad-bd45e385ab46",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "b92337f6-3727-4563-a1fd-2a7a065def89",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

I copied the onboarding controller from the sample [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet). When I try to sign up with an admin user from a different tenant, instead of the consent screen, I get the error:

```
AADSTS65005: Resource 'fc7ecdae-ec69-40a8-a88f-a859591fab07' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753162/how-to-get-a-token-for-downstream-service-in-aad/29755575#29755575), I should be able to have a single consent screen for my MVC app and its dependent services. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the instructions on this page to set up your access to local API resources?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132599.aspx

The error implies to me that your application or its exposed entitlements may not have been properly configured.

If you provide me with your tenant ID I can take a closer look as to the issues here.

Please, let me know if the above resource helps!
Thanks

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for your reply. AFAIK, I've done all the required steps in the linked document. The directory where the MVC app and services are registered is: cbe4b114-b82a-46c4-a76c-788c4c9f2ee8. I'm trying to sign up with the admin user from directory 49449efc-51d4-4a60-ae23-2ea949f5f1f5. The app works fine in single-tenant mode. I can share the manifest files somewhere if that helps.

Comment: Hi there, I believe the issue here is that your "resource application" SoapSvc (fc7ecdae-ec69-40a8-a88f-a859591fab07) is not multi-tenant. Thus, when your multi-tenant client application is trying to search for this resource, in a DIFFERENT tenant than where it is registered, it cannot find it. This might also explain why it does work when in single-tenant mode.

Can you try making your resource application multi-tenant?

Comment: Thanks Shawn, that was definitively an oversight. However, making the services multi-tenant does not fix the issue. I now get a slightly different error: We received a bad request. Additional technical information: 
Correlation ID: 810d92dc-ba43-486a-9093-fdad22b27b3b 
Timestamp: 2015-04-27 23:01:50Z 
AADSTS65005: The application needs access to a service that your organization YOAAD has not subscribed to.

Comment: Hi MvdD, sorry for the super delayed response here. Someone else ran into this issue recently and pointed me to this unanswered final question. The solution here is to add the client application as a 'well known client application' to the Web API. If you open the manifest for your web API there is a section called "knownClientApplications" where you can put the GUID of your client Application. Then, when a user consents to your Client App, it will also provision the service principal for your Web API into your tenant. I hope this helps you and others who run into this issue.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizy, thanks for following up. I do not have time right now to test this, but certainly will in the near future. I'll accept the answer when I've verified it. Is there a good overview of all the properties of the application manifest? I could only find https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835125.aspx

Comment: Hi MvdD, We actually do not have a good article on the Application Manifest, but one is being worked on now and will hopefully be released soon. I will try to remember to add it as a comment on this thread once it gets out there.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizy I finally got around to verify this. It did fix my issue. I've accepted the answer. It is very hard to find information on the "knownClientApplications" property (only found GitHub reference). Was the article on the application manifest ever published?

Comment: Hi, I think this is the article that got published. Can you let me know if it has the information you are looking for inside it?
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-manifest/

Comment: @ShawnTabrizy Well, it has the information, but not a clear explanation. This series of articles helped my more: https://github.com/mspnp/multitenant-saas-guidance